# Visualizing k-space tori in 3D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topology, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

In many introductions to topological insulators (in the exposition of Haldane’s model, for example), we represent the parameter space, a torus, on a plane with axes running from $0$ to $2\pi$.

In an attempt to visualize how curves on such a plane would look on a 3D torus, I started coding a model where I tried to use the standard parametrization of a torus in three variables (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html). 
However, I realized that I do not know what exactly determines the radii involved in the parametrization of the 3D torus.

I am guessing that the energy and any phase factors of the quantum mechanical system involved have a role to play in the radii - for example, with the on-site energy $ M $ and phase $\phi$ in Haldane’s model. I make this guess after seeing some diagrams of tori that appeared very thin near the Dirac cones.

However, I doubt a lot of my reasoning, and would like to know how to explicitly map a torus on the plane to a torus in 3D. I could not find any discussion of the topic in the several sources I consulted, except for the diagrams I mentioned.

Does anyone have helpful insight? Also, before anything, does it make sense to try and visualize the torus in 3D? I just want to see how a curve on the plane would look on a 3D torus and try to see for myself how other properties (Berry curvature and Chern number, for example) change depending on position in k-space. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The radii of the torus are related to the circumferences, i.e., the length of the Brillouin zone in each dimension. Maybe it would help to give more mathematical details of what exactly you're trying to plot?

Comment: Oh! I am trying to visualize how a circular loop drawn on the plane would look on a 3D torus’ surface. My approach is to parametrize the said loop on the honeycomb lattice (so, essentially a rectangle whose dimensions depend on the lattice vectors). For a series of $i$, the loop will be generated by $k_{x}(k_{i}=k_{x_{0}}+r \Cos[k_{i} x]$ (with a similar expression for $k_{y}$) using Mathematica. Then ideally I would plug these values into some parametrization in Cartesian coordinates for the 3D torus (which is still in k-space). For simplicity, the loop will not cross the boundary.

Comment: Clearly, if such a parametrization exists, it has to depend on the radii of the torus. I want to know how to explicitly know what radii I should use for a given $M$ and $\phi$ in the Haldane model. I hope to attempt to visualize the Hamiltonian for the Haldane model in a similar manner.

Comment: The BZ is defined independently of the hamiltonian — it only depends on the lattice geometry. The hamiltonian is just a (matrix-valued) function on the BZ. Whatever immersion of the BZ torus in $\mathbf{R}^3$ you choose shouldn't depend on the parameters of the hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Finally, do you know how the radii of the torus are related to the BZ’s dimensions? I’m guessing it’s a linear relationship, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: Well, I think it is somewhat arbitrary, but a natural choice would be to make the radii relate to the circumference (the length of the BZ) in each direction as $C=2\pi R$. So if your BZ is $\{0 \leq k_1 < 2\pi/L_1, 0 \leq k_2 < 2\pi/L_2\}$, the two radii (in $\mathbf{k}$ space, so they have dimension $\text{length}^{-1}$) would be $R_1 = 1/L_1$, $R_1 = 1/L_2$.